# drag and drop in protractor

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, protractor, automated-tests

I am trying to perform drap and drop element ; but not working as expected.

sourceStop:ElementFinder = element(by.xpath('//div[@class="ui-table-scrollable-body"]//tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0bhm.png)'));

destinationStop:ElementFinder =element(by.xpath('//div[@class="ui-table-scrollable-body"]//tr[2]'));

await browser.actions().dragAndDrop(source, dest).mouseDown().perform();

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top ng-tns-c23-216 ng-star-inserted"
    style="">
    <span class="ui-dialog-title ng-tns-c23-216 ng-star-inserted" id="ui-dialog-24-label">
        <p-header _ngcontent-c28="">
            <p _ngcontent-c28="" class="modal-prompt">Resequence Stops</p>
        </p-header>
    </span>

</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
    <div _ngcontent-c28="" class="modal-body">
        <p-table _ngcontent-c28="" scrollheight="350px">
            <div class="ui-table ui-widget">

                <div class="ui-table-scrollable-wrapper ng-star-inserted">
                    <!---->
                    <div class="ui-table-scrollable-view">
                        <div class="ui-table-scrollable-header ui-widget-header">
                            <div class="ui-table-scrollable-header-box" style="margin-right: 0px;">
                                <table class="ui-table-scrollable-header-table">
                                    <!---->
                                    <thead class="ui-table-thead">
                                        <!---->
                                        <tr _ngcontent-c28="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                            <th _ngcontent-c28=""></th>
                                            <th _ngcontent-c28="">Site</th>
                                            <th _ngcontent-c28="">Address</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="ui-table-tbody">
                                        <!---->
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-table-scrollable-body" style="max-height: 350px;">
                            <table class="ui-table-scrollable-body-table">
                                <!---->
                                <tbody class="ui-table-tbody">

                                    <tr _ngcontent-c28="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                        <td _ngcontent-c28="" preorderablerowhandle=""
                                            class="ui-table-reorderablerow-handle"> 1 </td>
                                        <td _ngcontent-c28="" preorderablerowhandle=""
                                            class="ui-table-reorderablerow-handle"> City Of Ashland 20Yd Recy </td>
                                        <td _ngcontent-c28="" preorderablerowhandle=""
                                            class="ui-table-reorderablerow-handle"> 201 Bass St, Ashland, MO 65010
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr _ngcontent-c28="" class="ng-star-inserted">
                                        <td _ngcontent-c28="" preorderablerowhandle=""
                                            class="ui-table-reorderablerow-handle"> 2 </td>
                                        <td _ngcontent-c28="" preorderablerowhandle=""
                                            class="ui-table-reorderablerow-handle"> City Of Linn Tank/recy 3O Ot
                                        </td>
                                        <td _ngcontent-c28="" preorderablerowhandle=""
                                            class="ui-table-reorderablerow-handle"> City Hall, Linn, MO 65051 </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <!---->
                        </div>
                        <!---->
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </p-table>
    </div>
</div>
<!---->
<div class="ui-dialog-footer ui-widget-content ng-tns-c23-216 ng-star-inserted" style="">
    <p-footer _ngcontent-c28=""><button _ngcontent-c28="" disabled="">
            OK </button>
       <button _ngcontent-c28=""> Close </button></p-footer>
</div>
<!---->
```

[image: Actual Result]

Comment: Known issue with chrome. Use `html-dnd` package instead. You can find it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd

Comment: @ tehbeardedone : thanks it worked